# How can I delete data from phones that won't start up?

Tags: security, factory-reset, privacy, formatting

I have 2 broken Android phones that won't power up. An LG G4 (bootloop issue, but bought used, so no warranty), and a Moto G3 that fell in a puddle. Neither will power up, so I can't remove my personal data from them. Is there any way to delete my data on these before recycling/selling for parts/donating? I don't know what to do with them. I don't want to risk my personal data being recovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physically breaking them is the only way to be relatively certain the data isn't compromised by someone else somehow.